# populate multiple dropdown data using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

This is how I am trying to populate two dropdowns in my component using `useEffects`.

```
function populate_dropdown_one_data() {
    return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5001/dropdownonedata");
}

function populate_dropdown_two_data() {
    return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/dropdowntwodata");
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    populate_dropdown_one_data()
      .then(result => {
        setDropDownOneData(result.data.data);
      });
  }, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
    populate_dropdown_two_data()
      .then(result => {
        setDropDownTwoData(result.data.data);
      });
  }, []);
```

This only calls `populate_dropdown_one_data` when the page loads.

If I combine `populate_dropdown_one_data` and `populate_dropdown_two_data` inside one `useEffect`, it only calls `populate_dropdown_two_data`.

How do I populate data for both the dropdowns when the page loads?

Comment: You could use `promise.all` `React.useEffect(() => Promise.all([populate_dropdown_one_data, populate_dropdown_one_data]).then(values => setDropDownData(values)) , [])`

Comment: both effects should have been called after initial render.

Comment: @JosephD.: I added `alert` in the `useEffects`. You are right. Both are called but only one makes the call to the server (`populate_dropdown_two_data`). I think I may have to use `async await` in `useEffects` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[State update is **not batched** for asynchronous operations](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-439632622).

You can `await` for both operations in one effect.

```
React.useEffect(
  () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const one = await populate_dropdown_one_data();
      const two = await populate_dropdown_two_data();

      setDropDownOneData(one.data.data);
      setDropDownTwoData(two.data.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  },
  []
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 async function load() {
  const [dropdown1, dropdown2] = await Promise.all([
    populate_dropdown_one_data(),
    populate_dropdown_two_data()
  ])
  setDropDownOneData(dropdown1.data.data);
  setDropDownTwoData(dropdown2.data.data);
 }

 load();
}, [])
```

Comment: this only makes ajax call for `populate_dropdown_two_data`.